# How to create image in php

Tags: php

I am creating image with php

code

```
$src = array ("22.jpg","33.jpg","44.jpg","55.jpg","66.jpg","77.jpg");    
                $imgBuf = array (); 
                foreach ($src as $link) 
                { 
                   switch(substr ($link,strrpos ($link,".")+1)) 
                   { 
                       case 'png': 
                           $iTmp = imagecreatefrompng($link); 
                           break; 
                       case 'gif': 
                           $iTmp = imagecreatefromgif($link); 
                           break;                
                       case 'jpeg':            
                       case 'jpg': 
                           $iTmp = imagecreatefromjpeg($link); 
                           break;                
                   } 
                   array_push ($imgBuf,$iTmp); 
                } 

                $iOut = imagecreatetruecolor ("35","210") ; 

                imagecopy ($iOut,$imgBuf[0],0,0,0,0,imagesx($imgBuf[0]),imagesy($imgBuf[0])); 
                imagedestroy ($imgBuf[0]); 
                imagecopy ($iOut,$imgBuf[1],0,35,0,0,imagesx($imgBuf[1]),imagesy($imgBuf[1])); 
                imagedestroy ($imgBuf[1]); 
                imagecopy ($iOut,$imgBuf[2],0,70,0,0,imagesx($imgBuf[2]),imagesy($imgBuf[2])); 
                imagedestroy ($imgBuf[2]); 
                imagecopy ($iOut,$imgBuf[3],0,105,0,0,imagesx($imgBuf[3]),imagesy($imgBuf[3])); 
                imagedestroy ($imgBuf[3]); 
                imagecopy ($iOut,$imgBuf[4],0,140,0,0,imagesx($imgBuf[4]),imagesy($imgBuf[4])); 
                imagedestroy ($imgBuf[4]); 
                imagecopy ($iOut,$imgBuf[5],0,175,0,0,imagesx($imgBuf[5]),imagesy($imgBuf[5])); 
                imagedestroy ($imgBuf[5]);
                imagepng($iOut); 

            //header ( 'Content-type:image/png' );
                // save the img to directory 

                $char='0123456789';
                $length=10;
                $max_i=strlen($char)-1;
                $value='';
                for($j=0;$j<$length;$j++)
                {
                $value.=$char{mt_rand(0,$max_i)};
                }
                $imageid=$value;
```

it giving error on page like

> ‰PNG  IHDR#ÒOuî² CIDATxœíÖ]ŒdÇUðÿ9§êÞþ˜™]ïìÇlbc‚ÀÐ†(@dQž
>   @"$ƒ”<°E‚XX`Y~ E D¼€"!ÂI’;Q$£°M¼ïzw½_3ÓÓÝ÷Ö×9<ôÌ¬óÄRê§V«Õ·»ÿU]uÏ)JÙ
>   ‚Ì€˜7€wâÕ½«¯^»Óçþå™åfÈ¹-š©
>   *6›çŸù¹÷ðêðÌ[í‰%üÈ]Ø†0‡8@@ÙL3¼Än‘×ãÞ«·žxôñ»×69àôú©e?ÊóÙÊx™’W+Ü”˜C1Vö4Üîowq÷zwë?ýI·u§,É~@½™@PF¼Ž'>ô»ÇýÚ‘áÊòêÒh8Hëá¬
>   Œ,eïÄ9îK ¡Lº½4ëºÙüÖ7Óä¿ø—Ø–€‡(™€b’
>   »øØ¹ß\K÷o¾ãÌúI&*‚lÙÁR4P£ÄEÕ‰P¢ó!Î}ë:ëEdÄ-gX_.ß¸òòök¯ûŸúöß£Mp~1'ç($àßo½-­ÿÀÛï][Z/1Ëloî½Ÿ‡PaÕa#¥›{4ÓÉ˜4—\Š9í%©FË'7ÓÕñÝîƒÅ_h¹@øNþÄû}ðØ­?6NsLªêü0ö¡q%ö#fÖ2²Óbð’´¨ªjS¸,¾GE.ì\x~÷ùO>ûØ
>   x`°"*¶ñ±|äÄÚ™ñÊ±Év§Á4X‰¶·Óõ†S‹½€½Ž£QFècÅcŒ¡OH
>   ˆ²ÝË¤Ï·ws›ë›'è$þûòþ:931þkû¸-Z;1Ÿv%ôÐ’c
>   ß¸&Lûaëgq:Ó>Í•àÃñ`¼:;EŠÉHBL­¸ºv<š¤É€†§†Ç¿õ¥¯ŸýÉì');¾óÂ·7ëÜ'
>   9ö¥ˆH\C–Çäß¼ùæ%Ýž #µs­¦áéptU–}±lST°F:£#úÃ£Ï}ù«g?HÊ Q<÷¥=5>–»b¢M¹uV 
>   †½8»<»úûŸ{ooa€xmïÓ|üÈÚÀ›Ï}/

how i can solve this

Comment: That's not an error, that's *the image data*.

Answer (score 4):

What you're seeing is the actual content of the image that's generated.  You do need to specify content/type, otherwise it will be assumed to be `text/plain` or `text/html`.  Your image seem to be PNG, so

```
header("Content-type: image/png")
```

should be sufficient.  I can see this line commented out - but it needs to be included.  One note though: it needs to go **before** the actual image data is output, so you need to move it to the top of your script (or at least above `imagephp` call).

**EDIT**: If you want to save the resulting image into a file rather than output it to the browser, then you need to pass the second parameter to `imagepng` function:

```
imagepng($iOut, $myfilename)
```

See [Imagephp documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagepng.php) for more details

**EDIT 2:** If you need to get the content of the created image to use elsewhere, you can use this trick:

```
ob_start();
imagephp($iOut);
$image_data = ob_get_clean();
```

Now you got the resulting image data in a variable and you can continue with your script.

Comment: but when i include that it show image on that page .and i dont need to show image on that page.

Comment: Then what are you trying to do?

Comment: i have have to display my page not image.

Comment: I don't think I follow you.  Then what's all the image manipulation for?

Comment: these are pieces of image from these  i am creating one image and these image are saved in database and file but i dint need to display image or content of image(²ÝË¤Ï·ws›ë›'è$þûòþ:931þkû¸-Z;1)